# How do I change the color of an anchorpane from the controller class?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

For a GUI I'm making the minimize, maximize, close buttons similar to that of Spotify by using an anchorpane for each 'button'. I created the buttons via scenebuilder and they are loaded to the class via fxml. I can't figure out how to call a particular instance of an anchorpane in the controller class to change its background color when the mouse enters or exits.

```
public static Stage primaryStage;

@Override

public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
{

    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1280, 800));

    ...

    this.primaryStage = primaryStage;

    etc.
```

is how the UI class is set up

I expect the color of the anchorpane to change when the mouse enters the bounds, but as of now I have no idea how to call it.

Comment: Add an event handler for that anchorpane perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, had to set an fxid to the anchorpane and then initiate it in the controller class after an @FXML.

Kinda like this:

```
@FXML
Anchorpane someButton;

@FXML
public void makeButtonWhite(MouseEvent event)
{
    someButton.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #ffffff");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most convenient way of doing this imho is using a stylesheet to assign the background.

```xml
<AnchorPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" stylesheets="@style.css">
    <children>
       <AnchorPane prefWidth="30" prefHeight="20" styleClass="my-button"/>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**style.css** (same directory as fxml)

```css
/* default style */
.my-button {
    -fx-background-color: blue;
}

/* style when mouse is inside the region */
.my-button:hover {
    -fx-background-color: red;
}
```

This allows you to easily add the style to multiple `Region`s; you simply need to add the style class it (`styleClass="my-button"`).

Answer (score 0):

you know the code method in scenebuilder there you can set on mouse entered and exited for a button, a label etc. then if for example the button with the id "closeButton" and the OnMouseEntered "closeButtonOnEntered" and the OnMouseExited "closeButtonOnExited"
this will be the code you need

```
public yourcontrollerclass {
     @FXML
     Button closeButton;

     @FXML
     private void closeButtonOnEntered() {
           //sets button red
           button.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #ff0000");
     }

     @FXML
     private void closeButtonOnExited() {
          //sets button your first color
          button.setStyle("-fx-background-color: transparent");
     }
}
```

this can be done with nearly every thing in sceneBuilder

I hope i could help you(sorry for my bad english)

Comment: You need my other post if you want to use this!

Answer (score 0):

the code you need for starting this must be the starting class

```
public class Class extends Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        // Load root layout from fxml file.
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();

        loader.setLocation(this.getClass().getResource("/Folder/File.fxml"));
        loader.setController(yourControllerClass());
        //only if you do something with the controller class afterwards
        YourControllerClass controller = loader.setController();

        Parent parent = loader.load();

        // Show the scene containing the root layout.
        Scene scene = new Scene(parent);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}